# Django admin template overriding not working on hosting

Tags: django, django-templates

In general, I have such a structure

```
project
     |project/
         |myapp/
         |templates/
             |admin/
                  |myapp/
                      |change_form.html
```

in the html file this code

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% block field_sets %}
     {# your modification here #}
{% endblock %}
```

everything is fine on the local server
but when uploaded to the hosting, there are no changes. What is the problem ?

Comment: did you run python manage.py collectstatic ??

Comment: @SuryaBista yes